# RDotNet function to add two user defined inputs giving errors

Tags: asp.net, r, ajax, asp.net-mvc, r.net

I wrote the following controller function in an ASP.NET MVC5 application to return the sum of 2 user defined inputs using the R function sum(). This compiles successfully but does not give any output.
It is giving  500 (Internal Server Error) since the ajax function is failing.

Can anyone please tell me where I am making mistake?

```
public JsonResult Sum(int? Text1,int? Text2)
{
    REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(); //
    REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

    return Json(engine.Evaluate("function(Text1,Text2) 
     {sum(Text1,Text2)}").AsFunction(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you need to post that too.

Comment: I have solved the problem myself. The correct code snippet for the controller function is as follows:                                                            
    var mySum = engine.Evaluate("function(x,y){return 
             (x+y)}").AsFunction();

            var v = engine.CreateInteger(Text1);
            var u = engine.CreateInteger(Text2);
            var sum1 = mySum.Invoke(new SymbolicExpression[] { u, v }).AsInteger();

            return Json(sum1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: Great! Happy to know that u solved that urself.

Comment: Please post this as an answer.

Comment: RDotNet function to add two user defined inputs giving errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself. The correct code snippet for the controller function is as follows:

```
var mySum = engine.Evaluate("function(x,y){return (x+y)}").AsFunction(); 
var v = engine.CreateInteger(Text1); 
var u = engine.CreateInteger(Text2);
var sum1 = mySum.Invoke(new SymbolicExpression[] { u, v }).AsInteger();    
return Json(sum1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
```

Since many of you messaged me asking for a sample code for the rdotnet application, I have published an example code with explanation on my blog: 
    [wordpress.com/post/pheonix116s.wordpress.com/169](https://wordpress.com/post/pheonix116s.wordpress.com/169)

I hope you all may find it useful.